# Please keep the "Where can I find ROMs?" question broadly useful

Tags: discussion, community-wiki, specific-question

In reference to [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/1465)

Lately the answer has gotten a few fairly localized additions that I have edited out.  In general I think we should only list sites that:

- Have ROMs for a large number of devices — targeting an entire manufacturer or more.
- Are up-to-date
- Are pretty popular and recognized as useful resources by the Android community
- Are somewhat well done and organized

And we should keep out sites that are too localized, half-baked, or generally not useful to a large portion of our users.  Without curation, we're just becoming an exceptionally poor version of a search engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there seems to be no disagreement I will accept this answer to keep the post from being bumped.